# Why my logo isn't displaying nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express

Here is a picture of my project directory.

[image]

I have my logo in the template/assets/logo.png.

In my server.ts file, I use middleware express as app.use( express.static( "template" ) );

unfortunately, When I try to display the logo in my html file, it doesn't display.

```
 <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="Logo">
```

Here is my server.ts file:

```
// Import everything from express and assign it to the express variable
import  express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
// Import WelcomeController from controllers entry point
import {WelcomeController} from './app/controllers';

// Create a new express application instance
const app: express.Application = express();



// The port the express app will listen on
const port: any = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Template folder
app.use( express.static( "template" ) );

// Mount the WelcomeController at the /welcome route
app.use('/', WelcomeController);


// Serve the application at the given port
app.listen(port, () => {

    const source = fs.createReadStream('/src/app');
    const dest = fs.createWriteStream('/dist');


    source.pipe(dest);
    source.on('end', function() { /* copied */ });
    source.on('error', function(err) { /* error */ });
    // Success callback
    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

What would be the way to display my templates with the files showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing this wrong `app.use( express.static( "template" ) );`

I should be doing `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app/template'));`

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to define what the root directory is first in express before importing assets (at least, it helps!)

so if you import express and then assign `express()` to a variable ,e.g.

```
 var express = require express(); 
 var app = express;
```

then you could do something like:

```
var root = require('path').join(__dirname,'/template');
app.use(express.static(root));
```

Once the root is defined, all further files will be called from that place when a url is referenced.

hope this helps